# Get data from my row mysql in javascript with php and json

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

There is a  problem with my code. i'd like to get my row from **mysql** to **js** using **json**. In **mysql**, i have just 2 columns : `startDate`, and `endDate`.
this is my php :

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "softdb";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Visibility");

    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    // returning response in JSON format
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

and this is my js :

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
var method = "GET";
var url = "data.php";
var asynchronous = true;

ajax.open(method, url, asynchronous);

ajax.send();

ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
    {
        // convert JSON back
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    }
}
```

but my console.log display an error :

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```

and if i check with

```
alert(this.responseText);
```

i have :

```
{'startDate': '["2018/2/1 22:26:56", "2018/2/1 23:58:46", "2018/2/2 01:33:11", "2018/2/2 09:07:18", "2018/2/2 10:36:16", "2018/2/2 12:10:23"]', 'endDate': '["2018/2/1 22:33:52", "2018/2/2 00:10:20", "2018/2/2 01:41:49", "2018/2/2 09:11:44", "2018/2/2 10:47:36", "2018/2/2 12:20:47"]'}[{"startDate":"[\"2018\/2\/1 22:26:56\", \"2018\/2\/1 23:58:46\", \"2018\/2\/2 01:33:11\", \"2018\/2\/2 09:07:18\", \"2018\/2\/2 10:36:16\", \"2018\/2\/2 12:10:23\"]","endDate":"[\"2018\/2\/1 22:33:52\", \"2018\/2\/2 00:10:20\", \"2018\/2\/2 01:41:49\", \"2018\/2\/2 09:11:44\", \"2018\/2\/2 10:47:36\", \"2018\/2\/2 12:20:47\"]"}]
```

there are two times the same values ...

thanks for the help !

Comment: So, if you open you php file in browser directly - what output do you see?

Comment: have you tried using mysqli_fetch_all() http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Comment: if i open my php file, i get the same output.. And i tried using mysqli_fetch_all(), same results...

Comment: Is that literally what it is printing out?  You have the same JSON twice there.  The first is formatted improperly, the second looks good...regardless, even if it was formatted properly, 2 separate json objects in a row would not be valid JSON.